# How to install jvm in oracle?

Tags: oracle, jvm

I am having trouble installing JVM in Oracle 9.2.0.6.0

I have attempted installation by running `$ORACLE_HOME/javavm/install/initjvm.sql`. But it throws error

```
ORA-06512: 在"SYS.INITJVMAUX", line 15.
```

When I look up the package body INITJVMAUX:

```
procedure exec (x varchar2) as
begin
dbms_output.put_line(substr(x, 1, 250));
execute immediate x;  --line 15
end;
```

and it's called by

```
-- Load all the Java classes
begin if initjvmaux.startstep('CREATE_JAVA_SYSTEM') then
  initjvmaux.rollbacksetup;
  commit;
  initjvmaux.rollbackset;
  initjvmaux.exec('create or replace java system'); --error
  commit;
  initjvmaux.rollbackcleanup;
  initjvmaux.endstep;
end if; end;
/
```

I need some help in getting this installed. The version is Oracle 9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.6.0.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps that needs to be carried out to re-install the JAVA Virtual Machine.

1.To uninstall (if already installed) the current installation of JAVA Virtual Machine, execute the following scripts at the SQL prompt connected as `sys` user.

> ```
>   startup mount;
>   alter system set "_system_trig_enabled" = false scope=memory;
>   alter system enable restricted session;
>   alter database open;
>   @?/rdbms/admin/catnojav.sql
>   @?/xdk/admin/rmxml.sql
>   @?/javavm/install/rmjvm.sql
>   truncate table java$jvm$status;
> ```

Once all the above commands have been executed successfully, restart the database. Shutdown of the database is necessary to ensure that the changes are synchronized with the disk after removal of JAVA Virtual Machine.

2.To install the JAVA Virtual Machine execute the following scripts at the SQL prompt connected as `sys` user.

> ```
> startup mount
> alter system set "_system_trig_enabled" = false scope=memory;
> alter database open;
> @?/javavm/install/initjvm.sql
> @?/xdk/admin/initxml.sql
> @?/xdk/admin/xmlja.sql
> @?/rdbms/admin/catjava.sql
> shutdown immediate;
> ```

3.Start the database and resolve any INVALID objects by executing the utlrp.sql script.

> @?/rdbms/admin/utlrp.sql

Now the JVM should be fully installed and functional.

> SQL> select comp_name, version, status from dba_registry;

Please go through Knowlege Mgmt Note `ID  757771.1 How to Reload the JVM in 10.1.0.X and 10.2.0.X`  in [Oracle Support](http://support.oracle.com) (formerly metalink ) to go through a much detailed step by step process (with video) to resolve any issues that you may be facing. This note also consists of several other Notes that resolve different issues.

Comment: I did like this, but it's failed on step one.And after run $ORACLE_HOME/javavm/install/initjvm.sql, then executed "select comp_name, version, status from dba_registry;", the status is LOADING.

Comment: Did you run un-install before running install again? did you restart the DB after un-install? Did you run the `utlrp` after re-install?

Comment: yeap, I run un-install before running install again, but it failed.And any user cannot login db but sys. Until I restart the database, it becomes normal.

Comment: Check the answer, I have updated it with an Oracle metalink note. That note should help you resolve. Also, make sure you restart the db between `un-install` and `install`.

Answer (score -2):

To install Oracle JVM, log into Oracle with SYSDBA privileges.
run this command in SQL*plus:

> SQL>@ORACLE_HOME\javavm\install\initjvm.sql

And then

> SQL> select COMP_NAME, VERSION, STATUS FROM dba_registry

to confirm JVM is installed correctly.

Comment: I did it like this, but fails.The reason is I said.

Comment: Have you completed Java memory requirements—You must have at least 20 MB of JAVA_POOL_SIZE and 50 MB of SHARED_POOL_SIZE.

Comment: @Badar I once again had to format several of your answers. Please learn how to properly format them yourself if you don't want to bump into similar issues as before.

Comment: Yes, I have learned some techniques; but it takes sometime. Don't mind everything will be ok.